# How to archive all the posts from a Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook

So I'd like to mass-save/back up all the comments from a Facebook Page (including expanded tabs). How would I do this?

I have a page that I manage whose comments I'd like to archive. But I'd also like to archive the comments from some other pages that I don't manage right now.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "archive".    Delete?    Take off-line to most people can't see them but you have a copy somewhere else?

Comment: Okay - I mean mass-save, so that I can have a backup copy.